Fix mutating trigger trigger in Oracle PL/SQL
I'm encountering a mutating trigger issue while attempting to update a table within a cursor select loop in my trigger.
The trigger fires after an update on the t_order_ table. The problem is due to the fact that the orderItems cursor is performing a select and subsequently, in the code, an update is performed on the same table.
This is the trigger:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AU_RESET_BUDGET
AFTER UPDATE ON t_order_
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

    pkMonthOrder base_month_order.pk_base_month_order%TYPE;
    pkBbMonth base_month_order.pdbo_base_budget_month%TYPE;
    pdboValue base_month_order.pdbo_value%TYPE;
    pdbmValidOrderedValue base_budget_month.pdbm_valid_ordered%TYPE;
    pdbmOrderedValue base_budget_month.pdbm_ordered%TYPE;

    CURSOR orderItems IS 
        SELECT pk_order_item
        FROM order_item
        WHERE poit_order = :NEW.popo_code;
    
    CURSOR orderBudget (pk_order_item INTEGER) IS 
        SELECT pk_base_month_order, pdbo_base_budget_month, pdbo_value
        FROM base_month_order
        WHERE pdbo_order_item = pk_order_item AND pdbo_is_valid = 0;
        
BEGIN
    IF (:NEW.popo_status != :OLD.popo_status) AND (:NEW.popo_status = 0) THEN
        FOR rec IN orderItems LOOP
            FOR rec2 IN orderBudget (rec.pk_order_item) LOOP
                IF rec2.pdbo_value > 0 THEN
                    UPDATE base_month_order
                    SET pdbo_value = 0
                    WHERE pk_base_month_order = rec2.pk_base_month_order;
                    
                    SELECT pdbm_ordered INTO pdbmOrderedValue FROM base_budget_month WHERE pk_base_budget_month = rec2.pdbo_base_budget_month;    
                                        
                    UPDATE base_budget_month
                    SET pdbm_ordered = pdbm_ordered - rec2.pdbo_value
                    WHERE pk_base_budget_month = rec2.pdbo_base_budget_month;
                    
                    UPDATE order_item
                    SET poit_boolean1 = 1
                    WHERE pk_order_item = rec.pk_order_item;
                    
                    SELECT pdbm_valid_ordered INTO pdbmValidOrderedValue FROM base_budget_month WHERE pk_base_budget_month = rec2.pdbo_base_budget_month;
                    
                    IF pdbmValidOrderedValue > 0 THEN
                        UPDATE base_budget_month
                        SET pdbm_ordered = pdbm_valid_ordered - rec2.pdbo_value
                        WHERE pk_base_budget_month = rec2.pdbo_base_budget_month;    
                    END IF;
                    
                END IF;
            END LOOP;
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
END AU_RESET_BUDGET;
/


This is the update that is causing the problem:
UPDATE order_item
SET poit_boolean1 = 1
WHERE pk_order_item = rec.pk_order_item;

I understand that mutating triggers occur when a trigger attempts to read or write the same table that is being modified, but I'm struggling to find an efficient solution. At the moment, I'm considering using a job to perform the update outside of the trigger context, but this solution is not optimal due to scheduling concerns and potential failure.

Cascading foreign key constraints ?

You have not provided definitions for your tables or sample data to test against so this is difficult to test; but if you stop using cursor loops (since you are trying to update values that the cursor is reading inside the loop) and, instead, just use SQL then your query could become something like:
CREATE TYPE number_table IS TABLE OF NUMBER(10,0);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AU_RESET_BUDGET
AFTER UPDATE ON t_order_
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_order_items number_table;
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.popo_status != 0
     OR :NEW.popo_status IS NULL
     OR :OLD.popo_status = 0
  THEN
     RETURN;
  END IF;

  UPDATE order_item
  SET    poit_boolean1 = 1
  WHERE  poit_order = :NEW.popo_code
  RETURNING pk_order_item BULK COLLECT INTO v_order_items;

  UPDATE base_month_order
  SET    pdbo_value = 0
  WHERE  pdbo_order_item IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_order_items));

  MERGE INTO base_budget_month dst
  USING (
    SELECT pdbo_base_budget_month,
           pdbo_value
    FROM   base_month_order
    WHERE  pdbo_order_item IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_order_items))
  ) src
  ON (dst.pk_base_budget_month = src.pdbo_base_budget_month)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET pdbm_ordered = CASE
                       WHEN dst.pdbm_valid_ordered > 0
                       THEN dst.pdbm_valid_ordered - src.pdbo_value
                       ELSE dst.pdbm_ordered - src.pdbo_value
                       END;
END TCI_AU_RESET_BUDGET;
/

fiddle
